# Include paths in Visual Studio search or otherwise reach views

Tags: search, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Often when working on MVC projects in Visual Studio, I find myself with several folders for different views like `User/index.cshtml` and `Admin/index.cshtml` when using the `control+,` search, however, it is difficult to pick these out of the list. Typing Admin/index will produce no results as it doesn't seem to consider the path and typing just index.cshtml will bring up a long list making it hard to find the file you're after.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: This might be irrelevant as today Visual Studio 2017 was released with what appears to be the feature I'm looking for. Still if anyone knows a solution for 2015 I would be curious.